# How to impose two conditions at once for Apache CustomLog?

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd.conf

I currently have separate access logs for static and dynamic pages. My **httpd.conf** has (inside **<VirtualHost>**):

```
<LocationMatch "^/(img|js|css|thumb|banner)/(.+)$">
SetEnv static 1
</LocationMatch>

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gopal.log myCustom env=!static
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gopal-static.log myCustom env=static
```

I would like to complement it with

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "127.0.0.1" dontlog
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gopal.log myCustom env=!dontlog
```

, but cannot find an example of using CustomLog **expr=** parameter and cannot guess a working expression:
`expr=!(reqenv('static')||reqenv('dontlog'))`
produces

> syntax error, unexpected T_OP_OR

Answer (score 8):

The `reqenv` function must be compared against something, you cannot just check for the environment variable to be set or not as your code tries to. I admit the error message is not particularly enlightening :-)

The following should work for you:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/(img|js|css|thumb|banner) static=yes
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "127.0.0.1" dontlog=yes

CustomLog logs/access_log myCustom expr=!(reqenv('static')=='yes'||reqenv('dontlog')=='yes')
```